# Перебор ассоциативного массива в ReactJS

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, strapi

Данный пример моего кода работает, но мне нужно получить не конкретный элемент массива, а все его элементы.

Прилагаю структуру массива:

[image: Структура массива]

Судя по всему необходимо использовать `forEach` внутри функции `map`, но у меня почему то так не работает:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
/* import { Link } from 'react-router'; */

import Strapi from "strapi-sdk-javascript/build/main";

const strapi = new Strapi("http://localhost:1337");
//const BLOG_URL = 'http://localhost:1337';

class Faq extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const posts = await strapi.getEntries("categories?id=7");
      this.setState({ posts });
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const productItem = this.state.posts.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <section className="b-productsContainer">
          <span className="b-productItem" key={index}>
            {/*  <img className="news-preview-img" src={BLOG_URL + item.products[0].img.url} alt="" />  */}
            <p>{item.products[0].author}</p>
            <h4>{item.products[0].title}</h4>
          </span>
        </section>
      );
    });

    return <>{productItem}</>;
  }
}

export default Faq;
```

Помогите пожалуйста отрендерить все элементы массива `products`

Comment: делай точно так же как и с posts

Comment: Внутри метода map еще раз юзать этот же метод??

Comment: А почему нет? :-)

Comment: Можно посмотреть пример кода?

Comment: например так`{ item.products.map(product => <><p>{product.author}</p><h4>{product.title}</h4></>) }`

Comment: Да, большое спасибо. Так действительно все заработало)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уже используете метод [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) для генерации постов из props'ов, так что будет достаточно добавить еще один цикл:

```
const productItem = this.state.posts.map(item => (
    <section className="b-productsContainer" key={unique_key_1}>
        <span className="b-productItem">
        {item.products.map(product => (
            <React.Fragment key={unique_key_2}>
                <p>{product.author}</p>
                <h4>{product.title}</h4>
            </React.Fragment>
        ))}
         </span>
    </section>
   )
)
```

Отдельно хочу отметить что не стоит использовать `index` в качестве уникальных идентификаторов таких как `key`.